# Generalization of Totient Function

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, totient-function

Totient function gives us the count of of all numbers(k) upto n which satisfy the equation gcd(k,n)=1. 
How can I find the count of all such k's which satisfy gcd(k,n)=d for some natural number d?

Comment: Hint: (k,n)=1 implies (dk,n)=d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $d$ divides $n$, then $\gcd(k,n)=d \implies \gcd(k/d, n/d) = 1$ so the count of such values you'd be looking for is [$\phi(n/d)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function).